# Search an array - replace values with values from another array in C

Tags: c, arrays, loops, search, replace

I am new to programming and I trying to build different kinds of fun little applications in order to understand the basics. I have started with C to really start out at the bottom, so the below refers to C.

So basically I have to arrays a[] and replace[], which are both 200 long filled with random numbers.

I want to search a[] for the value 32 (ele) and replace any occurrence of that value with the corresponding value in replace[].

E.g. if: a[22] = 32, replace[22] = 78 => a[22]=78

At the same time I would like it to 'record' the index number (22) and log that to a file.

I can't get it to go through a[] multiple times and replace every instance. It only replaces 1 instance and then breaks.

I have no error msg. for below code. Hope you can help a newbie out.
If you have the answer, please also take a minute to explain how/why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

FILE *ifp, *ofp;

int ix;
int ik;
int i;
int change;
int count = 0;
int ele = 32;
int num = 200;
int a[200];
int replace[200];   


void swap(int a[], int replace[], int change)
{
    int temp = replace[change];
    a[change] = replace[change];
    a[change] = temp;

    ifp = fopen("/Users/kjaerolsen/tmp/ilog.txt", "a+");

    fprintf(ifp, "%d\n", change);

    fclose(ifp);
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // creates array with random numbers to draw new numbers from.
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int ik = 0; ik < 200; ik++)
    {
        rand();
        replace[ik] = rand() % 200; // / rand_max;
    }

    for (int ik = 0; ik < 200; ik++)
    {
        fprintf(ifp, "%d\n", replace[ik]);
    }
    // creeates main array with random numbers.
    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int ix = 0; ix < 200; ix++)
    {
        rand();
        a[ix] = rand() % 200; // / rand_max;
    }

    for (int ix = 0; ix < 200; ix++)

    {
        printf("plads %d i array: %d\n",ix, a[ix]);
    }

    // Looks for number 32 (ele) in array
    i = 0;
    for (int i =0; i < 200; i++)
    {
        change++;
        swap(int a[], int replace[], int change)
        count++;

    }

    if (count == 0)
        printf("%d is not present in array.\n", ele);
    else
        printf("%d is present %d times in array.\n", ele, count);

    // Opens the file and rewrites the new array. 

    ifp = fopen("file1.txt", "w+");
    for (int ix = 0; ix < 200; ix++)
    {
        fprintf(ifp, "%d\n", a[ix]);
    }

    fclose(ifp);

    printf("very done...");
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Don't call `srand` multiple times. And there's no need for the extra `rand` call in the initialization loops.

Comment: First observation, format your code in such a way that it's the most readable. And always check for functions which could potentially fail, for example `fopen()` returns `NULL` when a problem happens, check for that. Avoid global variables unless you really know what you're doing, and precisely avoid them when you don't know why you need them.

Comment: As for your problem, always post any compiler errors, complete and unedited, in your question. And you *do* know how to call functions takings arrays? You have done it multiple times, even in this program (hint: look at those `printf` calls) so you know how to do it, and how to call functions in general. It's *not* done the way you attempt to call your `swap` function.

Comment: where are you giving value to `change`?

Comment: Also, you don't actually *check* if you should do the swapping or not, you do it on *every* element in the arrays.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I didn't know about the `rand`. Great to know. Do you suggest that I create a function with the `rand`, and the call it?
@iharob You are most certainly right about formatting. I haven't really learned about good practice for this - can you suggest a resource. On the `fopen()`; you are right. However, I know this is not the problem as I do get the corresponding files. The ilog.txt seems to have from 1-200 in it.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I am sure you are on to something, but I have to say that you will need to explain more thoroughly what I am doing wrong. I think I might be too  newbs to get what you mean.

Comment: @PrakharSingh oh dear. Yes, I updated the code because it had gone missing in my posting.

Comment: `swap(int a[], int replace[], int change)` cannot compile.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY it seems to compile. Especially if I remover the IFs. Then it actually logs one instance of changing the value.

Comment: You must call this function in the following manner. `swap(a, replace, change);` note : `change` are counting up before it is called.

Answer (score 0):

Must fopen ifp before the second loop and fclose it after. Your current code goes segmentation fault:

```
ifp = fopen( ... );
for (int ik = 0; ik < 200; ik++)
{
    fprintf(ifp, "%d\n", replace[ik]);
}
fclose( ifp );
```

Also, you can swap with three XOR:

```
a ^= b;
b ^= a;
a ^= b;
```

and no temp variables;

Comment: Thanks this really helped! I can't upvote - but I would if I could :)

Answer (score 0):

A tremendous thanks for all your help. I finally succeeded in making it work - and it is beautiful. I moved it out of an actual function and in to the loop, since there was no reel need to call a function. Secondly, I was missing the top `IF`. But most important @micarelli your suggestions with XOR did the trick.

Maybe not much for a couple of hardcore coders like yourself, but it was really satisfying. 
I posted the final snippet of code below.

```
    i = 0;
    for (int i =0; i < 200; i++)

    if (a[i] == ele)
{
    a[i] ^= replace[i];
    count++;
}

    if ( count == 0 )
    printf("%d is not present in array.\n", ele);
    else
    printf("%d is present %d times in array.\n", ele, count);

// Opens the file and rewrites the new array. 

    ifp = fopen("/Users/kjaerolsen/tmp/file1.txt", "w+");

    for (int ix = 0; ix < 200; ix++)

{
    fprintf(ifp, "%d\n", a[ix]);
}

    fclose(ifp);
```